# How to set a layout default value from parent layout using databinding and <include> tag in order to see it in preview?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm trying to use a view with databinding using the include tag multiple times.
It works great when the app runs, but in preview I don't manage to make it work in the parent.
Instead, I can do it on the view itself, but it implies that if I use it 5 times in the same layout, I'll have 5 exact copies. It's not a blocking issue, but for debugging/ UI, it makes things a bit more complicated.

Here's the code of the replicated view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <import type="android.text.TextUtils"/>
    <variable
      name="title"
      type="String" />
    <variable
      name="value"
      type="String" />
  </data>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:text="@{(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) ? title : `Title`).concat(`:`), default=`Title:`}" />


    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="@{!TextUtils.isEmpty(value) ? @color/darkBlue : @color/red, default=@color/red }"
      android:text="@{(!TextUtils.isEmpty(value) ? value : `Unknown`), default=`Unknown`}" />

  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And here's how it's included:

```
<include layout="@layout/titled_entry"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         bind:title="@{`Firstname`}"
         bind:value="@{user.firstName}" />
```

[In Android it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wa3J.png)

[But in preview it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el0xl.png)

Does anyone know how to fix it ?

Thanks, and have a good day in those complicated times.

Answer (score 1):

Store your string in string.xml

And set that as default value

Like below

```
android:text='@{viewModel.firstName, default=@string/firstName}`
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It doesn't change anything, I can't access "android:text" from the include. If I do that, I would have "Firstname" as a title for each field, which is no different than "Title". What I need is to set it inside the <include> tag, where I have no access to "text" and have to set it from the binding, but the binding only seems to happen if the app runs. I'm looking for something like tools to set it in the preview only perhaps.